# Universal Apps MessageBox: "The name 'MessageBox' does not exist in the current context"

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

I want to use MessageBox for showing download errors in my WP8.1 app.

I added:

```
using System.Windows;
```

but when I type:

```
MessageBox.Show("");
```

I get error:

```
"The name 'MessageBox' does not exist in the current context"
```

In Object Browser I found that such class should exist and in "Project->Add reference... ->Assemblies->Framework" is shown that all assemblies are referenced.

Do I miss something? Or is there another way how to show something like messagebox?

Answer (score 127, accepted):

For Universal Apps, the new APIs require you to use `await MessageDialog().ShowAsync()` (in Windows.UI.Popups) to bring it into line with Win 8.1.

```
var dialog = new MessageDialog("Your message here");
await dialog.ShowAsync();
```

Comment: This whole Async business is like a virus. You start putting it in one place and it spreads to everything, making you refactor a large amount of code. Not sure if this is intended or I am doing something wrong

Comment: @Rajiv afaik it is intended, but let me know if you find anything that is against/supports this, let me know.

Comment: @Rajiv: it does not spread throughtout your code if you make your calling method async with void (or any other return type than Task/Task<>). The async keyword in the containing method declaration per se does not call for any refactorings!

Answer (score 48):

Just wanted to add to ZombieSheep's answer: also, customization is quite simple

```
        var dialog = new MessageDialog("Are you sure?");
        dialog.Title = "Really?";
        dialog.Commands.Add(new UICommand { Label = "Ok", Id = 0 });
        dialog.Commands.Add(new UICommand { Label = "Cancel", Id = 1 });
        var res = await dialog.ShowAsync();

        if ((int)res.Id == 0)
        { *** }
```

Answer (score 30):

try this:

```
 using Windows.UI.Popups;
```

code:

```
private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        MessageDialog msgbox = new MessageDialog("Would you like to greet the world with a \"Hello, world\"?", "My App");

        msgbox.Commands.Clear();
        msgbox.Commands.Add(new UICommand { Label = "Yes", Id = 0 });
        msgbox.Commands.Add(new UICommand { Label = "No", Id = 1});
        msgbox.Commands.Add(new UICommand { Label = "Cancel", Id = 2 });

        var res = await msgbox.ShowAsync(); 

        if ((int)res.Id == 0)
        {
            MessageDialog msgbox2 = new MessageDialog("Hello to you too! :)", "User Response");
            await msgbox2.ShowAsync();
        }

        if ((int)res.Id == 1)
        {
            MessageDialog msgbox2 = new MessageDialog("Oh well, too bad! :(", "User Response");
            await msgbox2.ShowAsync();
        }

        if ((int)res.Id == 2)
        {
            MessageDialog msgbox2 = new MessageDialog("Nevermind then... :|", "User Response");
            await msgbox2.ShowAsync();
        }


    }
```

To Trigger some Function When "Yes" or "No" is clicked, You can also use:

```
msgbox.Commands.Add(new UICommand("Yes", new UICommandInvokedHandler(this.TriggerThisFunctionForYes)));
msgbox.Commands.Add(new UICommand("No", new UICommandInvokedHandler(this.TriggerThisFunctionForNo)));
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also make a class like the next one. Below the code a usage example:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Windows.UI.Popups;

namespace someApp.ViewModels
{
    public static class Msgbox
    {
        static public async void Show(string mytext)
        {
            var dialog = new MessageDialog(mytext, "Testmessage");
            await dialog.ShowAsync();
        }
    }

}
```

The example to use it in a class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
namespace someApp.ViewModels
{
    public class MyClass{

        public void SomeMethod(){
            Msgbox.Show("Test");
        }

    } 
}
```

Comment: This implementation doesn't mimic the same thread blocking behavior as the original MessageBox and could be very confusing for new developers.

Answer (score 2):

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page {
    public MainPage() {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    public static class Msgbox {
        static public async void Show(string m) {
            var dialog = new MessageDialog( m);            
            await dialog.ShowAsync();
        }
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) { 
        Msgbox.Show("This is a test to see if the message box work");
        //Content.ToString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For new UWP apps (starting from Windows 10) Microsoft recommends using [ContentDialog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.contentdialog) instead.

**Example**:

```
private async void MySomeMethod()
{
    ContentDialog dlg = new ContentDialog()
    {
        Title = "My Content Dialog:",
        Content = "Operation completed!",
        CloseButtonText = "Ok"
    };

    await dlg.ShowAsync();
}
```

**Usage**:

```
private void MyButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   MySomeMethod();
}
```

**Remark**: You can use different styles etc. for the `ContentDialog`. Please refer to the link above for various usages for ContentDialog.